# Hide/show table rows

Tags: javascript, html

I am preparing a html table with >100 different names, but I  only want some rows to show up. So far I use a javascript to "hide" everything and then "show" for those I want to show in the table. Is there a way to make the script hide EVERYTHING by default, and then use "show" for those I want to appear in the final table?

Here is the code for a basic example with only 5 different names (John, Ida, Thor, Diana, Chris) where I want Diana and Christ to show.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<script src="jquery/jquery-1.12.2.js"></script>

<table id="subtable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> 
        <tr>
            <td>John</td>       
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ida</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Thor</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Diana</td>  
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Chris</td>
        </tr>
</table>


<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready( function() {

$('#subtable td:contains("John")').parents("tr").hide();
$('#subtable td:contains("Ida")').parents("tr").hide();
$('#subtable td:contains("Thor")').parents("tr").hide();
$('#subtable td:contains("Diana")').parents("tr").hide();
$('#subtable td:contains("Chris")').parents("tr").hide();

$('#subtable td:contains("Diana")').parents("tr").show();
$('#subtable td:contains("Chris")').parents("tr").show();

});
</script>       
</html>
```

Comment: What's wrong with `$('#subtable td').parents("tr").hide();` ?

Comment: Hi Brian. The code is working fine. The problem is that I have more than 100 names (>100 hides) and I need the table on more than 100 different html pages, so whenever I want to add a new name to the list I need to make a hide on every page.

Comment: @J.Birch See my updated answer that addresses your issue.

Comment: Wow that is brilliant Scott. Can I ask you one more, a bit more complicated question about this?

Comment: @J.Birch I mean, why can't you just have one .hid() call that applies to all the rows in your table?  You don't need to force your selector to apply to just one element, do you?

Comment: No you are right, thanks a lot. Do you know if I can have the table in a Dynamic Web Template, which is editable locked? My table contains >100 different names and shows up at more than 100 different html pages and I want each html page to show a table with only some of the names which I specify for each page, and which are different from page to page. Do i make sense?

Comment: Sorry Brian, You already answered this in your previous answer... Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to make the script hide EVERYTHING by default

This is easily done by applying a CSS class that hides content:

```
.hidden { display:none; }
```

to all the the rows:

```
$("tr").addClass("hidden");
```

> and then use "show" for those I want to appear in the final table

The showing of the rows is done with JavaScript/JQuery to simply remove the `.hidden` class from those elements with another class identifying them as ones to be shown.

```
<tr class="shown">
```

Here's an example:

```js
$("tr").addClass("hidden"); // Hide all rows
$("button[type='button']").on("click", function(){
  // Remove the hidden class from rows that have the "shown" class
  $(".shown").removeClass("hidden");
});
```

```css
/* Apply this class to elements that should be hidden */
.hidden { display:none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="subtable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> 
        <tr class="shown">
            <td>John</td>       
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ida</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="shown">
            <td>Thor</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Diana</td>  
        </tr>
        <tr class="shown">
            <td>Chris</td>
        </tr>
</table>

<button type="button">Show Appropriate Rows</button>
```